# I don' t find layout.blade.php on my laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

[image]
[image]

I cant find `layout.blade.php` only `welcome.blade.php`. I installed a 5 project laravel 6, 5.8 , 5.4 and the same problem. I'm using wampserver but for laravel 6 I need php 7.2+ so I uninstalled it and reinstalled it and the problem began where i cant find `layout.blade.php`.

please someone help me

Comment: There is no `layout.blade.php` in Laravel

Comment: It's not a default file. You have to create your own layout.blade.php. [welcome is the only default file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/resources/views)

Answer (score 1):

Its not default file.you can add it in every folder you like in view.

Create `blade` view and just write `@yield('YourContentName)` in where you like that will render by childs.
Its too simple.

Answer (score 1):

Create a directory in views called layouts and then add app.blade.php to it. So it would be resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php. Add your layout to that file, something as simple as to start if you like:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        @yield ('content')
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in your welcome.blade.php you want:

```
@extends ('layouts/app')

@section ('content')
    <p>Stufff here will show within the yield.</p>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

you must make a file in resources where this model will be the base for other templates, and in this base template you can put css and a basic HTML structure, for example the basic bootstrap template.

Answer (score 0):

Use `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` from https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend#introduction

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder named Layout and create a file inside it, for example app.blade.php, and place it under the view folder and use the keyword @yield to display the content of other files in this file.